# A High-Load Application to read Data from Redis and Insert into Cassandra

Tags: python, node.js, cassandra, redis

Here are requirements which I need to satisfy:

- Redis will have about 1 - 80000 writes every 10 seconds.
- The application has to read each write from Redis and write it onto
  Cassandra.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

The application should be either in Python or Node.js but more packages can be installed on top of it.